# Typescript: how do I build an interface containing both an object and a string index type?

Tags: typescript

I need to describe an interface where:

1. A property with a 'billingAddress' key has a value of an Object with specific properties, and
2. Properties with any other key have a value of a string.

I tried this:

```
interface DoesNotWork {
  [key: string]: string;
  billingAddress?: {
    foo: string;
  }
}
```

Typescript complains that `Property 'billingAddress' of type '{ foo: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type`

Fair enough: when `DoesNotWork.billingAddress` is defined, Typescript won't know whether it should be assigned a `string`, an `object` or `undefined`.

How do I describe the interface in a way that Typescript will understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use discriminated union so you can mix and match.

```
interface DoesNotWork {
  billingAddress?: {
    foo: string;
  };
}

const foo: DoesNotWork | { [key: string]: string } = {
  billingAddress: { foo: "value" },
  key: "value"
};
```

Comment: Seems to work great! I threw in a type definition as well:

type Customer = DoesNotWork | { [key: string]: string };

const foo: Customer = ...

Answer (score 0):

With using **Index Signatures** because the exact propertyName is not known at compile-time, but the general structure of the data is known, creating a **separate interface**, to accommodate this data, and afterward **composing the Interfaces** to achieve the desired object structure, should help solve your problem **OR** extend using **union types** to increase the flexibility of values which are expected

This is because in trying to define different fields in the same interface, then you must **cater for the option**, of different (values) for the other fields aside from the **Index Signature field**

demo code

```
//composition approach(1)
interface BillingAddress{
  foo: string;
}

interface DoesNotWork{
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface ComposedInterface{
  indexSignature: DoesNotWork,
  billingAddress? : BillingAddress,
}


//extending value fields using unions approach(2)
interface BillingAddress{
  foo: string;
}

interface DoesNotWork{
   [key: string]: string | BillingAddress;
   billingAddress: BillingAddress;
}
```

Comment: For (1):
it looks like you define a property called `indexSignature`, whose value is intended to be an object containing a property whose key is any string, and whose value is a string. But we want the mapped type a level up, where you put the `indexSignature` property.

(2) comes closer: `billingAddress`'s type is restricted to an object with specific properties. But with `[key: string]: string | BillingAddress`, we can now define anything to be a `BillingAddress`. We want only the `billingAddress` key to use the value `BillingAddress`. Anything else should be a string.